# How to prevent text blur when I turn pages in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I turn the pages using jQuery, the text in the page becomes blur.

This is the function I am using to turn the pages:

```
$('#book').turn({
    display: 'double',
    autoCenter: true,
    acceleration: true,
    elevation: 150,
    page: nrPage,
    when: {
        first: function (e, page) {
            $('.nav_arrow.prev').hide();
        },

        turned: function (e, page) {

            if (page > 1) {
                $('.nav_arrow.prev').fadeIn();
                $('#about').hide();
            }
            if (page == 1) {
                $('#about').css('z-index', 11);
            }
            if (page < $(this).turn('pages')) {
                $('.nav_arrow.next').fadeIn();
            }
            update_fonts();
            $(this).setPage(page);
        },
        turning: function (e, page) {

            if (page < 2) {
                $('#about').show();
            } else {
                $('#about').css('z-index', 5);
            }
        },

        last: function (e, page) {
            $('.nav_arrow.next').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Need some guidance to ensure that the text does not become blur. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Is the text in an image or in real text?

Comment: Though I'm not entirely sure, I doubt that you can prevent that.

You have to keep in mind, that there is a constant recalculation of the font and that's why the font will not be antialiased while in transition. Once the animation stopped, it will be antialiased again.

Comment: @Christoph thanks a lot. I am adding a custom font and it appears blur when in transition. How to avoid that? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Webkit supports some proprietary version of the non-standard [`font-smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth):

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: [none | subpixel-antialiased |antialiased];
```

So this might help for webkit browsers when using `antialiased` instead of the standard `subpixel-antialiased`. Not sure what you can do in the other browsers, since this is non standard and not supported in any other browser.

You did not include the `turn()` but if you are doing 3d-transformations modern browsers hand the computation task over to the graphics card which might return better results, so using the 3d form of any transform might improve the result too:

```
#elem{
   /* instead of: */
   transform: translateX( 20px );
   /* do this: */
   transform: translate3d( 20px, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the post is quite old, though someone can still be looking for that info :)
You should set acceleration to to false. That should solve the problem.